# Real line as a product topological space

Tags: general-topology

Let $\Bbb R$ be endowed with the standard topology. Clearly, we can trivially represent
$$
  \Bbb R \cong \Bbb R^0\times \Bbb R \tag{1}
$$
and also, there is not such topological space $X$ that $\Bbb R \cong X^2$. Thus, I wonder whether necessary
$$
  \Bbb R \cong X\times Y
$$
implies that $X = \Bbb R^0$ and $Y = \Bbb R$ (or vice-versa). With $\Bbb R^0$ I mean the singleton topological space $1$.

Comment: What does the notation $\mathbb R^0$ mean?

Comment: The projections onto $X$ and $Y$ must mean that both are connected. So the argument seems to reduce to the one showing $\Bbb R$ is not $X^2$.

Comment: @MattN.: sorry, that's just a singleton

Comment: [t.b.'s answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/57382/8348) to your previous question would seem to work _mutatis mutandis_ in this case as well.

Comment: @ArthurFischer: you're right indeed, if you post it as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[t.b.'s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/57382/8348) to your previous question would seem to work *mutatis mutandis* in this case as well:

> If $\mathbb{R} = X \times Y$, then both $X$ and $Y$ are path connected.  If both $X$ and $Y$ have cardinality $> 1$ it follows that removing any single point from $X \times Y$ yields a path connected space, but the real line clearly does not have this property.