# Is $\mathbb R^n$ the product of anything not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^p$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

One has $\mathbb R^n=\mathbb R^p\times\mathbb R^q$ whenever $p+q=n$. My question is whether or not one can choose different factors in the product.

> Do there exist topological spaces $A,B$ so that $A\times B\cong \mathbb R^n$ for some $n$ and $A\not\cong \mathbb R^p$ for any $p$?

Intuitively: no way. But I have no idea how I would tackle such a problem, I can't even tell if it is simple or incredibly difficult.

Comment: By "cross product", do you mean the "cartesian product"?

$$A \times B = \{ (a,b) : a\in A \ \wedge \  b \in B\}$$

The "cross product" works on pairs of vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ and gives something perpendicular.

Comment: @FlybyNight yes, the cartesian product of topological spaces. Sometimes this is called "Kreuzprodukt" in german, it may be incorrect to use the corresponding word in english.

Comment: Yes. Look up Whitehead manifolds. They are contractible three manifolds. If you take the Cartesian product of one of them with $\mathbb{R}$ you get $\mathbb{R}^4$.  I bet the Cartesian product of two of them is six space.

Comment: @CharlieFrohman Interesting, thank you.

Comment: There are even worse examples: There is a space $B$ constructed by Bing (the "dogbone space") which is not even a manifold, but $B\times R$ is homeomorphic to $R^4$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57375/mathbb-r-x2-as-a-cartesian-product